# Django help - how to get data from foreign keys

Tags: python, django

Given the following model setup (stripped down):

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ObjectVersion(models.Model):   
    Cabinet = models.ForeignKey(Object)
```

Say I had a bunch of `ObjectVersion` entries that I'd filtered called "filteredObjects". How would I get the names of those objects into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `values_list` or `values`. The docs are available on the Django QuerySet API reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

```
>>> ObjectVersion.objects.filter(...).values('Cabinet__name')
[{'Cabinet__name':'foo'}, {'Cabinet__name':'foo2'}, ...]
```

or

```
>>> ObjectVersion.objects.filter(...).values_list('Cabinet__name')
[('foo',), ('foo2',), ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

so you are saying that you have a list called `filteredObjects`?

```
objNames = [fo.name for fo in filteredObjects]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ObjectVersion.objects.filter(your filters here).values_list('Cabinet__name', flat=True)
```

Output:

```
  result = ['ver_1', 'ver_2'..]
```